# How do you input a Python Variable into a section of xml code in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, xml, aws-lambda

I am using code to send sms messages through AWS Lambda and Twilio. The code works correctly as below:

```
if ('Body') in format_message:
    message_body    =   (format_message['Body'])
        return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
               '<Response><Message>Hello %USER'S NAME% </Message></Response>'
```

However anything in the  string sends as plain text.

I want to put insert a variable into the %USER'S NAME% section of this message. The variable would be set in the python code - how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a string. Do whatever you would normally do to insert content into a string.

If you are using Python 3, you can use f-string formatting:

```py
return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
       f'<Response><Message>Hello {user_name} </Message></Response>'
```

Comment: Specifically, Python 3.6+ implements f-string.

Comment: Thats fantastic thank you! not sure why I was trying to make it more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `.format()`?

```
if ('Body') in format_message:
message_body    =   (format_message['Body'])
    return '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'\
           '<Response><Message>Hello {} </Message></Response>'.format(user_name)
```